# spaCy : issue in finding ROOT word in sentence using Dependency Parsing

Tags: nlp, spacy

I am trying to parse the following sentence using spaCy:

```
text = "Parsley Energy to acquire Jagged Peak Energy in an 
          all-stock deal."

doc = nlp(text)
for token in doc:
    print(token.text, ' ====> ', token.dep_)
```

> This gives me **Energy** as Root verb which is not correct.

But if I slightly change the sentence i.e. from **to acquire** to **will acquire**:

```
new_text = "Parsley Energy will acquire Jagged Peak Energy in an 
            all-stock deal."
```

> I get the Root verb correctly as **acquire**.

is there a way I can get acquire as Root verb in first case as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should first be noted that the root is not necessarily a verb (see [here](https://universaldependencies.org/u/dep/root.html) and [here](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/11144/what-is-the-root-of-an-utterance-without-a-verb)).
The root is the one node that is not dominated by one of the other nodes.

Non-finite clauses contain a verb which does not show tense.
for example:
"The person to win the competition"
in this example it is pretty clear that the root is "person" and "win" is a dependent of "person"

in the same way if we have:
"the company to acquire Jagged Peak Energy in an all-stock deal." 
it would also be clear that the root is "company"

Your first example:
"Parsley Energy to acquire Jagged Peak Energy in an all-stock deal."
is less obvious 
I think it is an ellipsis, the omitted word in the elliptical sentence being "is".
The sentence would normally be "Parsley Energy *is* to acquire .."

see [here](https://universaldependencies.org/u/dep/root.html):

> If the main predicate is not present (due to ellipsis) and there are multiple orphaned dependents, one of these is promoted to the head (root) position and the other orphans are attached to it.

To conclude, it does not appear that Spacy is making an error here.